# inner height of browser at client side in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have silver light application.i want inner height of browser, i got it while running in localHost but when i am deploying it then it would give me error like.

object references not set to an instances of object

I have used following code to get the inner height of browser.

following code resides at client side.i have set the resolution at server side.

```
HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("innerHeight");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that **Application.Current.MainWindow** should help you in Out-of-Browser Application.

And [good article about Out-of-Browser Application](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/out-of-browser-applications/building-an-out-of-browser-application) may be useful for you.

Comment: oops.. what do you mean with "when i am deploying it"? Upload to an external server? And what is the server side?

Comment: In which place you try to get the height? (app, somepage.xaml.cs)